# QCheckBox detect click on label

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qcheckbox

Is there any way to detect if the user clicked on the label on a `QCheckBox` or not? If so, I want to execute something and the checkstate should not be changed .. to checked or unchecked.

So far I can not find any signals / ways for that ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event filter is the answer.

First install event filter on a check box for which you want to change behavior (during construction):

```
ui->checkBox->installEventFilter(this);
```

and then reject mouse press event when mouse is over the label (note how label is localized in code):

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *o, QEvent *e)
{
    if (o==ui->checkBox) {
        QMouseEvent*mouseEvent = static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(e);
        if (e->type()==QEvent::MouseButtonPress &&
                mouseEvent->button()==Qt::LeftButton) {
            QStyleOptionButton option;
            option.initFrom(ui->checkBox);
            QRect rect = ui->checkBox->style()->subElementRect(QStyle::SE_CheckBoxContents, &option, ui->checkBox);
            if (rect.contains(mouseEvent->pos())) {
                // consume event
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(o,e);
}
```

I've test it on Qt 4.8.1 for Linux and it works as you want (mouse clicks on a label are ignored and on check box it toggles state of check box).

Comment: I don't use an extra `QLabel`. I do use the one from `QCheckBox`. However I wanted to detect a click on that text, from `QCheckBox`.

Comment: so what is wrong with [those signals](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qabstractbutton.html#signals): `clicked(bool)`, `pressed()`, `released()`? Why did you accept answer with subclassing `QLabel` (this suggest that you use separate QLabel)?

Comment: Cause: `I want to execute something and the checkstate should not be changed .. to checked or unchecked.` and thats not possible

Comment: it is possible, event filter allows to lots of stuff without subclassing. I gave you a scratch of it, I'm pretty sure it requires improvement. Without details it is hard to tell what exactly you suppose to do.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: see an update, I'm pretty sure this is what you want. In other cases you should be able to tweak this to you needs.

Answer (score 2):

`QLabel` doesn't have an accessible 'on click' method, however you can subclass `QLabel` and reimplement the `mousePressEvent(QMousePress *ev)` slot which will allow you to do click detection.

Comment: Yup I also found that here. http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/8355-QLabel-clicked%28%29